# Align/avoid numeration and labels in a custom biblatex format

Tags: biblatex, formatting

I need list references with a custom format, with a label showing the type of entry (`@article`, `@book`, etc.) and labeling fix/variable fields in a tabular environment. I have successfully obtained  this (see MWE below), but I still need to control/improve some aspects:

1. **Avoid numeration** (How I can suppress `[1]` and `[2]` in the MWE?)
2. **Vertical position** of the number of reference and their label ("Article"). How to move both to the top (unrotated) or at the same level that the first field, but both rotated, to save left space?
3. **How to center correctly the main label** (Article) when rotated 90º as in the MWE?
4. **How to avoid the extra labels** `DOI` and `URL`?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[backend=biber, maxnames=99, sorting=none, hyperref=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@ARTICLE{mwe2012,
  author = {Smith, A. and Johnson, B. and Willians, C.},
  title = {The three most common surnames in the United States of America},
  journal = {Review of Useless Knowledge},
  year = {2012},
  volume = {8},
  number = {1},
  pages = {290--290}
}

@ARTICLE{mwe2011,
  author = {Miller, J. and Brown, D.},
  title = {Most used surnames in fake passports},
  journal = {Journal of Nosense Ranks},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {5},
  number = {3},
  pages = {1--130},
  pmid = {1234567},
  url = {http://www.mwe.com/mwe2011},
  doi = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/jnr.2011.01.01},
}



\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}  

\AtEveryBibitem{
\ifentrytype{article}{\begin{sideways}Article\end{sideways}}{}
}

% \DeclareNameFormat[article]{author}{\dotfill #1 \dotfill}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{title}{\bf #1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\emph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{volume}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{year}{#1}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
\begin{tabular}{lp{0.75\textwidth}}     \\ 
 \textcolor{gray}{Authors:}   & \printnames{author}       \\ 
 \textcolor{gray}{Title:}    & \printfield{title}        \\  
 \textcolor{gray}{Year:}       & \printfield{year}         \\
 \textcolor{gray}{Journal:}   & \printfield{journaltitle} \\ 
 \textcolor{gray}{Volume:}   & \printfield{volume}       \\
 \textcolor{gray}{Number:}    & \printfield{number}       \\
 \textcolor{gray}{Pages:}   & \printfield{pages}        \\
 \iffieldundef{url}{}{\textcolor{gray}{\sc url:}     & \printfield{url}     \\}%
 \iffieldundef{doi}{}{\textcolor{gray}{\sc doi:}     & \printfield{doi}     \\}%
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1em}
\hrule
\usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=My example articles]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To avoid numeration use `style=authoryear` as one of the option of `biblatex`

For the vertical position of the `Article` label `\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Article}` instead of the `sideways` environment (It is not clear to me if you want the reference number with Article)

For removing DOI and URL use `\DeclareFieldFormat{x}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{#1}}` where `x` is either `url` or `doi`.

[image]

To keep the  reference numbers and to have them (vertically rotated) with the Article label, an option is to redefine `bibliography`

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\ifentrytype{article}
       {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{
         \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
             \printfield{prefixnumber}%
              \printfield{labelnumber}}%
            \addspace%
            \MakeSentenceCase{\thefield{entrytype}}}}
       {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
         \printfield{prefixnumber}%
         \printfield{labelnumber}}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

In  particular we change the fist  argument where we change the argument of `\list` which defines the default label. With  this solution there in no need to use at `\AtEveryBibitem`, and one can use the `numeric` option for `style` (or leave `style` out)

[image]