# How to change the format of biblatex references to have 3 columns (alpha, author, 'Titel and other information')?

Tags: biblatex

I need to customize my references in the following style using `biblatex`s Alpha style having the columns Label, Author, and Title and Other Information.

[image]

Till now with your help I could already change the square brackets to slashes.

My code so far is:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
 .
 . 
 \usepackage[%
natbib        = true,
backend       = bibtex8, %bibtex, biber
style         = alphabetic,
%citestyle     = alphabetic,
maxcitenames  = 2,
mincitenames  = 1,
%bibstyle      = alphabetic, %authoryear, %draft, %,
sorting       = nyvt,
maxbibnames   = 6,
minbibnames   = 6,
language      = ngerman,
date          = long,
backref       = false,
backrefstyle  = none,  % none, three, two, two+, three+, all+
firstinits=true 
]{biblatex}
   \usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
   \bibliography{input/literatur} 

   \newrobustcmd{\mkbibslashes}[1]{/#1/}

    \DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{\mkbibslashes{#1}}
   \DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{\mkbibslashes{#1}}

   \DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibslashes]
   {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
   {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
\usebibmacro{cite}}
   {\multicitedelim}
   {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

  \renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}
  .
  .
  .
```

Thanks again

Comment: yes, unfortunatetly it is the rules of my research Institute. The rules  are as i described them 3 coulmns in the first is the Label, in the second the author and in the last the rest of the Information. Thats  all. Thanks a lot

Comment: not answering the question, but please use ragged right at least in the author column.  the huge gap between last name and initial (in the case of multiple authors) is most unsettling.

Comment: Maybe [tabular bibliography with biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71088/35864) and [Tabular bibliography with 2 cols for `@inbook`, `@article` etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/157359/35864) can give you an idea.

Answer (score 3):

Well, your question is not so easy as you perhaps think.

You are using `biblatex` and style `alphabetic`.  Therefore you need to check the files `standard.bbx`, `alphabetic.bbx`,  `alphabetic.cbx` and at last (if needed) you have to check and search in path (for MiKTeX) `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex` for related informations.

In file `standard.bbx`  you can find the definitions for the layout for articles, books, etc.  For example we look to the driver for `article`:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

Based on [the linked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157359/tabular-bibliography-with-2-cols-for-inbook-article-etc) you can now use the following code (I did it only for article! If your `bib` file contains `book` etc you have to add the relevant drivers too):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{mwe2012,
  author  = {Smith, A. and Johnson, B. and Willians, C.},
  title   = {The three most common surnames in the United States of America},
  journal = {Review of Useless Knowledge},
  year    = {2012},
  volume  = {8},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {290--290},
}
@ARTICLE{mwe2011,
  author  = {Miller, J. and Brown, D.},
  title   = {Most used surnames in fake passports},
  journal = {Journal of Nosense Ranks},
  year    = {2011},
  volume  = {5},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {1--130},
  pmid    = {1234567},
  url     = {http://www.mwe.com/mwe2011},
  doi     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/jnr.2011.01.01},
}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
article{einstein,
  author  = {Albert Einstein},
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German}) 
             [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{array}    % > in table
\usepackage{ragged2e} % \RaggedRight in table

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[%
  backend      = biber, 
  maxnames     = 99, 
  sorting      = nyvt, 
  hyperref     = true,
  maxcitenames = 2,
  mincitenames = 1,
  natbib       = true,
  giveninits   = true, % firstinits
  style        = alphabetic
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,breaklinks]{hyperref}



\newrobustcmd{\mkbibslashes}[1]{/#1/}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{\mkbibslashes{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{\mkbibslashes{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{mkbibslashes}{\mkbibslashes{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}                  % no punct after entry

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibslashes]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}\usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}



\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\ifentrytype{article}
       {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{
         \printtext[labelalphawidth]{% mkbibslashes
           \printfield{prefixnumber}%
           \printfield{labelalpha}%
           \printfield{extraalpha}}%
            %\addspace%
            %\MakeSentenceCase{\thefield{entrytype}}%
       }}
       {\printtext[labelalphawidth]{% mkbibslashes
          \printfield{prefixnumber}%
          \printfield{labelalpha}%
          \printfield{extraalpha}}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%\labelnumberwidth or \labelalphawidth
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}% \hss##1
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{#1}}



% \DeclareNameFormat[article]{author}{\dotfill #1 \dotfill}
%\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{title}{\bf #1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{title}{\enquote{#1}}%\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\emph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{volume}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{S.~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{year}{#1}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
\begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedRight}p{0.2\textwidth}>{\RaggedRight}p{0.68\textwidth}}\\ 
  \printnames{author} & 
    \printfield{title}\newunit \printfield{year}\newunit  
    \printfield{journaltitle}\newunit \printfield{volume}\newunit
    \printfield{number}\newunit \printfield{pages}\newunit 
    \printfield{url}\newunit \printfield{doi}\newunit \\%
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1em}% 1em
\hrule
\usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*} \cite{mwe2011}
\printbibliography[title=My example articles]
\end{document}
```

To save a little bit space it is nice to rotate the label for 90 degrees.  If you do not want this please change the code

```
   {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{
     \printtext[labelalphawidth]{% mkbibslashes
       \printfield{prefixnumber}%
       \printfield{labelalpha}%
       \printfield{extraalpha}}%
        %\addspace%
        %\MakeSentenceCase{\thefield{entrytype}}%
   }}
```

to

```
   {%\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{
     \printtext[labelalphawidth]{% mkbibslashes
       \printfield{prefixnumber}%
       \printfield{labelalpha}%
       \printfield{extraalpha}}%
        %\addspace%
        %\MakeSentenceCase{\thefield{entrytype}}%
   }%}
```

and change the line

```
  {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%\labelnumberwidth or \labelalphawidth
```

to

```
 {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelalphawidth}%\labelnumberwidth or \labelalphawidth
```

I added some `bib` entrys to show you that you need to add the relevant drivers for `book` etc.

With the code

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedRight}p{0.2\textwidth}>{\RaggedRight}p{0.68\textwidth}}\\ 
  \printnames{author} & 
    \printfield{title}\newunit \printfield{year}\newunit  
    \printfield{journaltitle}\newunit \printfield{volume}\newunit 
    \printfield{number}\newunit \printfield{pages}\newunit 
    \printfield{url}\newunit \printfield{doi}\newunit \\%
\end{tabular}
```

I defined the needed tabular for your needs.  Please see that you have to play with the width of the two columns `p{0.2\textwidth}` and `p{0.68\textwidth}`.  With `{\RaggedRight}` I forced a **left** justified layout for both columns (better, because the lines becomes very short).

The two lines

```
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}                  % no punct after entry
```

changes the sign between units to comma (as shown in your screenshot) and deletes the closing punct for each entry.

At last the two lines

```
\vspace{1em}% 1em
\hrule
```

divedes each printed entry with a horizontal rule.  I personaly do not like that and would delete it.

You need to add similar drivers for the other types of entrys ...

Then I get the result:

[image: result of changed mwe]

Please see that this is a starting point, you need to complete it. But with the given information it should be possible ...