# Customizing biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have problems customizing my own `biblatex` style. It should look like that:

[image: screenshot of desired output, a proper description follows below]

I tried it over the weekend  after reading [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex?lang=de) and [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles). I thought that it would be easier to customize an already existing style (in my example the `authortitle` style) but maybe it would be easier to create a new one. But I only get errors and I'm quite under time pressure with the deadline so I hope someone can help me out.

**EDIT:** Things that need to be changed:

Generally:

1. date format: dd.mm.yyyy.

Article:

1. remove "In:"
2. title of journal, year, issue number, (all in italics) page number.

Oral(Interview):

1. show interviewer
2. add before interviewer's name: Interview: [interviewer's name]
3. date, address.

Electronic:

1. title in quotations mark and not in italics
2. Remove "URL:"
3. Remove brackets around "last visited at"
4. show institution

I add a MWE and one of my many approaches to customize the `authortitle` style (the approach will be quite useless).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{article,
    author  = {Peter Adams}, 
    title   = {The title of the work},
    journal = {The name of the journal},
    year    = 1993,
    number  = 2,
    pages   = {201-213},
}

@book{book,
    author    = {Peter Babington}, 
    title     = {The title of the work},
    address = {Berlin},
    year      = 1993,
}

@Oral{dean,
  author      = {Dean Rusk},
  interviewer = {David O'Brian},
  date        = {21.08.1970},
  year        = {1970},
  address     = {Boston},
}

@Electronic{pan,
  author      = Phlip Pan
  institution = {The New York Times},
  date        = {118.11.2018},
  year        = {2016},
  title       = {The West was sure the Chinese approach would not work. It 
   just had to wait. It's still waiting.},
  url         = 
  {https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2018/11/18/world/asia/china- 
  rules.html},
  urldate     = {18.11.2018},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
Some famous linguists wrote a couple of books  \cite{article} \cite{book} 


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I think to it's easier to customise an existing style. What are the differences with the authortitle style?

Comment: Also, please consider asking several questions each about a particular aspect of your style. Writing a complete style can be a huge task and is generally too much to ask for in one question (that does not mean you won't get an answer, though). Can you at least list the required changes for your style that need to be applied assuming we start from a standard `style=authortitle`?

Comment: I hope now it's clearer what I mean.

Comment: Thank you for editing your question. I still think that your chances of getting useful help quickly would increase if you were to split your question into several sub-questions, each about one particular issue. People sometimes feel that they should not be asking too many questions, but questions are free. And if you do a bit of research you may find the answer to one or two of the items already. Also please make sure that your MWE actually has the `.bib` entries to reproduce the screenshot. There is currently no `@online` and no interview entry.

Comment: For the in: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864. The MWE does not show dates with finer granularity than year, so I can only guess, but you could try the option `alldates=terse`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right, I need to add the two missing .bib entries and complete dates. I managed to solve some of the problems but when I am trying to combine them I somehow mess it up. I thought that the question as a whole makes more sense but when you say otherwise I'll split it up.

Comment: I wrote about why it makes sense to split questions up into several smaller ones in https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864. You do have a *lot* of questions, so it makes sense to chunk them a bit (I'm not sure if there is a question limit, especially if many questions turn out to be duplicates), but one question which practically just says: Please write this style is hard to answer and less useful for future visitors.

Comment: @glp You have an example of a very  different  custom format [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79001/align-avoid-numeration-and-labels-in-a-custom-biblatex-format),  but It should give you some clues to start and then ask for mor specific problems, if any.

Comment: All `date`-like fields in `biblatex` (`date`, `urldate`, ...) must be filled in ISO 8601 format (`YYYY-MM-DD`) regardless of the desired output format. `urldate = {18.11.2018},`will not work as expected, it should be `urldate = {2018-11-18},`. There is no point in giving both a `date` and a `year` in an entry - you should only give one of the two. The author field in `pan` is missing its curly braces. This will produce errors and the entry will not compile correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Questions asking to implement an entire style are always a bit hard to answer and take a lot of time, it is usually a *much* better idea to ask about specific features of the style. The compartmentalised nature of `biblatex` styles usually allows for an easy combination of answers (and should that not be the case it is always possible to ask a new follow-up question about combining two answers). In the last couple of days there was a series of questions that seemed to work towards building the style shown here, so I thought I'd collect the answers here to make sure this question has an answer.

Firstly, there are a few syntax errors in your `.bib` file. Dates in `date` fields must be given in ISO 8601/EDTF format (`yyyy-mm-dd`), so `urldate = {18.11.2018},` is wrong, it should be `urldate = {2018-11-18},` instead. That should immediately solve the date issue. Though you may want to use the option `dateabbrev=false`.

Furthermore, there was an issue with the `author` field in `pan`, it must be `author = {Phlip Pan},`.

You should also not give both a `year` and a `date` field. `date` alone should be enough.

- For the "In:" there is the classic [Suppress "In:" biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864).
- I did not find a question for the desired format of `journal`, `date` and `volume` (admittedly I didn't look very hard), so I have thrown something together in the MWE below (the block with `journal+issuetitle`).
- An implementation of the `@interview` type can be found in [Create interview bibliography type with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464361/35864) and [Custom type disappears in subsequent citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464756/35864), though a few changes are needed for the `authortitle` citation style.
- The necessary modifications for `@online` can be found in gusbrs' answer to [Sort authors and organizations alphabetically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464911/35864) and in [Move date before title in bibliography using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464205/35864) as well as [Add a point after the URL with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464383/35864).  Note that we use `organization` instead of `institution`, see [Show institution with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464004/35864).

We end up with

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{article,
  author  = {Peter Adams}, 
  title   = {The title of the work},
  journal = {The name of the journal},
  year    = 1993,
  number  = 2,
  pages   = {201-213},
}
@book{book,
  author    = {Peter Babington}, 
  title     = {The title of the work},
  address   = {Berlin},
  year      = 1993,
}
@interview{dean,
  interviewee = {Dean Rusk},
  interviewer = {David O'Brian},
  date        = {1970-08-21},
  address     = {Boston},
}
@online{pan,
  author       = {Phlip Pan},
  organization = {The New York Times},
  date         = {2018-11-18},
  title        = {The West was sure the Chinese approach would not work.
                  It just had to wait. It's still waiting.},
  url          = {https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2018/11/18/world/asia/china-rules.html},
  urldate      = {2018-11-18},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{interview.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{interview}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{
  interviewer,
  interviewee,
}

\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[interview]{
  addendum,
  doi,
  eprint,
  eprintclass,
  eprinttype,
  interviewer,
  interviewee,
  location,
  note,
  pubstate,
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[german=swiss]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, datamodel=interview, style=authortitle, dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{date}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{pages}{#1}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464756/35864
\NewBibliographyString{interview}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  interview   = {Interview},
}

\DeclareNameAlias{interviewee}{author}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{interview}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printnames{interviewee}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \bibstring{interview}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printnames{interviewer}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{nty}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{interviewee}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
}

\DeclareLabelname{%
  \field{shortauthor}
  \field{author}
  \field{shorteditor}
  \field{editor}
  \field{translator}
  \field{interviewee}
}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \ifentrytype{interview}
      {\bibstring{interview}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \printnames[family]{interviewer}}
      {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}}


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464205/35864
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  urlseen = {visited at} 
} 



\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareListWrapperFormat{organization}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464383/35864
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \usebibmacro{url}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\newunitpunct}%
     \usebibmacro{urldate}}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}




\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem  \cite{article} ipsum \cite{book,dean,pan} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Adams, Peter. «The title of the work». The name of the journal, 1993, 2, 201–213.//Babington, Peter. The title of the work. Berlin, 1993.//Pan, Phlip. The New York Times. 18. November 2018. «The West was sure the Chinese approach would not work. It just had to wait. It’s still waiting.» https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2018/11/18/world/asia/china-rules.html. Besucht am 18.11.2018.//Rusk, Dean. Interview David O’Brian. Boston, 21. August 1970.]

A few details may be missing, but this should capture the overall feel of the style.

Comment: Generous old moewe! I hope Santa takes that into account this year.  :-)