# Modify style of article references in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

The current article style looks like: [image]

But it should look like:

[image]

Due to my very limited biblatex skills I'm unfortunately not yet able to customize it as the article should look like.

What do I have to add to the code?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{asmz,
  author  = {Hans Zimmer},
  title   = {Minimal music},
  journal = {Some journal},
  year    = {2013},
  number  = {12},
  pages   = {40-41},
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Let's cite! \footcite{asmz}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some fiddling with the `journal+issuetitle` bibmacro alongside with some formatting directives should get things as intended. Notice I had to make some decisions regarding the order of other fields you didn't consider in your example, with repercussions on punctuation. I also use babel to get localized bibstrings such as "Nr.".

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{asmz,
  author  = {Hans Zimmer},
  title   = {Minimal music},
  journal = {Some journal},
  year    = {2013},
  number  = {12},
  pages   = {40-41},
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{date}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibemph{\bibstring{volume}~#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibemph{\bibstring{number}~#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{pages}{\mkbibemph{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Let's cite! \footcite{asmz}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}` should be the default and can be dropped. The `\printtext` around the `issue` and `date` serves no obvious purpose any more and can also be dropped. You may also want to make sure that the date and volume are in italics. Cf. also the only original bits of my answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/460611/35864 (where I made each field italic on its own and did not apply italics to the overall result, the result for punctuation would be slightly different).

Comment: @moewe I had completely missed the italic parts in the question. The other are welcome improvements too. Thank you!