# biblatex citation style & bibliography style

Tags: lyx

Im using LyX 2.3.6 together with JabRef 5.9 and achieved to get a grip on the software itself, writing, citing etc.
So far so good.
The last and biggest problem that remains is the following:
[image]

How can I make it so that the quotes I insert from JabRef via lyxpipe into LyX are automatically adjusted in formatting to predefined formatting defaults.

As I understand it, by the right combination of a suitable biblatex default style with additional commands in the "Options" lines (see photo) I can make it possible to specify how the imported bibtex data from JabRef is finally output in LyX or the PDF in the footnotes and the bibliography.

I also picked up elsewhere that in this case something like a "biber sourcemap" could help to achieve these goals.

Is there anyone among you who can help me with this? I'm just desperate because time is running out and I don't feel capable of overcoming this last hurdle.

In my university's guidelines are the following requirements that I must meet:

---

FOOTNOTES:

common sources like books:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/hK04qma.png]

internet sources:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/mhsXSjt.png]

---

BIBLIOGRAPHY:

Monographies:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/Up2cQGx.png]

Articles:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/aboZycQ.png]

internet sources:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/1vtRvt1.png]

I know that most of you will not understand German but I hope the way of formatting is comprehensive anyway?
Am I imagining it too easy with the implementation?

Or is it possible without any problems?

How would you proceed?

Is all that possible to realize? Is it even a LyX-thing or would I have to change settings in JabRef as well? I also have zotero installed + better bibtex plugin, but never used it. Maybe that's a better choice to combine with Lyx for reaching those special citation formats?

I also have read about a similar topic here: https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?p=111546&sid=dfb13d38f3a3d84c458b391f1db9a940#p111546
That seems quite helpful and it seems like the user @moewe ist active here as well, but I am just overwhelmed by all the possibilities so that its hard for me to filter what I actually need for those goals, without making things complicated for no reason..

Comment: There are many biblatex and bibtex styles out there, but the hard part is know if your exact requirements match with some existing style. If you cannot find one, another option a bit more complex, is make your own [custom format in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79001/align-avoid-numeration-and-labels-in-a-custom-biblatex-format) or your own [style in bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96174/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-or-personalize-bst-files).